How to use a Model Adapter in a User Defined Functions (UDF) for Pipeline Builder
We have been looking at the User Defined Functions (UDF) that can be used in Pipeline Builder for use of custom functions.
We would like to know if it would be possible to use a Model Adapter API within a UDF in order to infer all the rows of input data.
Does anyone tried such implementation?

As of April 16, 2024 it’s not possible to use a model adapter directly in pipeline builder. You will need to export your results to a dataset and use a python transform or a batch deployment in a modeling objective.
Palantir product is currently scoping this work, I will update this stackoverflow answer when it is possible to use palantir_models
